# how to make an IP address public so devices can connect and use the computer connected to the IP as a websocket server

Tags: c#, networking, websocket, portforwarding, shutdown

The concept is simple:
A smartphone has an app that has only 1 button, pressing the button makes a call to a websocket server (my PC, the websocket runs in background on startup) when the websocket recieves the button's press it shutsdown the pc, i have all the logic and code ready but i need to know how to make it so that whenever the 2 are (es. pc in London, but phone in Italy) they can still communicate with eachother. i thought of using port forwarding but i don't know much about networking and how it works. Is there a way to make the IP public or port forward the router so that it achieves what described above? note that i don't care much about the security of the app because i am the only one who will be using it.

P.S. the code is written in c#.

Comment: Most routers haves a section dedicated to port forwarding. There are many [tutorials](https://portforward.com/router.htm) out there you can follow. If you can't port forward(because of CGNAT or something else), you can opt for tunneling instead. There are services like https://ngrok.com/ for this

Comment: You only can use the Public IP address assigned by you internet carrier.  So you cannot make your private address public.  So you need to use Port Forwarding to relay the message from the Public IP address to the private IP address.